# instance member "myVar" cannot be used on type "myStruct"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos, cocoa-touch

I have a struct called `MyCategories` that I want it to have a sharedInstance that will be a dictionary of a few categories and keys.

I'm trying to do it like that:

```
private var sharedCategoriesDictionaryInstance: [String: MyCategories] {
        let first = MyCategories(title: "First", categoryIconName: "FirstIcon", markerIconImageName: "FirstMarkerIcon")
        let second = MyCategories(title: "Second", categoryIconName: "SecondIcon", markerIconImageName: "SecondMarkerIcon")

        return ["First":first, "Second":second]
    }

    static var sharedInstance: [String: MyCategories] {
        return sharedCategoriesDictionaryInstance //ERROR: Instance member 'sharedCategoriesDictionaryInstance' cannot be used on type 'MyCategories'
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Instance member 'sharedCategoriesDictionaryInstance' cannot be used on
>   type 'MyCategories'

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: *Hint:* One property is static, the other isn't.

Comment: @MartinR :) thanks